# Knitr produces different value

Tags: r, knitr

I'm trying to create html file from Rmarkdown in Rstudio.

Below shows a different values in the table. I try to delete the chunk files and restart the Rstudio but nothing change.

[image]

Comment: Trees are random. Try to set your random seed with `set.seed` first. Result in console and in the html might be different because of it

Comment: Please try reading up on how to ask a question, that can be answered by others: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

There are several ways to provide data, probably adding the output of `dput(<yourData>)` or `dput(head(<yourData>))` to your question is sufficient. 
Avoid adding code or alphanumeric output as images. 
Consider how to make a good example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example and see how you can change your question accordingly.